# Wordpress Gutenberg or React - useSelect for dynamic data

Tags: react-redux, wordpress-gutenberg

I am posting this here rather than in the WordPress dedicated site because I feel it is a question of more general applicability, though the specifics are Gutenberg.

I have this:

```
const test =  useSelect(
            ( select ) => wp.data.select('core').getEntityRecords('taxonomy', 'grammar1', {per_page: 100}),
                []
        );
console.log("test", test);
```

according to the Gutenberg documentation useSelect "useSelect is a custom React hook which uses the core useCallback hook in React" - the constant test will be updated with a changed value and the containing component will re-render.

This is fine - but the problem is I want to do this n times for e.g. grammar1, grammar2, grammarN - these values are not known in advance and the number of them is not known in advance. So - I get these dynamically, and this is fine. Let's say they end up in an array:

```
terms = ["grammar1", "grammar2", "grammar3"]
```

Now I want to use the above logic on each term in this array. I can see intuitively (without really understanding why) that this is going to be a problem and indeed it is:

```
const test2 = [];
 terms.forEach((item) => {

        test2[item] =  useSelect(
            ( select ) => wp.data.select('core').getEntityRecords('taxonomy', item, {per_page: 100}),
                []
        );
    });
```

Produces a redux error:

Switching useSelect from mapping to mapping is not allowed

Can anyone see what I am trying to do and how I could do it?

(My alternative is to do all this server-side and add a custom endpoint so I can do it in one call but I want to see if the above can be made to work, or, perhaps understand why not).

Thank you