# Wordpress: Built a gutenberg custom block in edit.js, and getting a useSelect error when trying to view page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

Here is my error
[image: error message]

Here is my code
edit.js

```
import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';
import {
    useBlockProps,
    InspectorControls,
    PanelColorSettings
} from '@wordpress/block-editor';
import {
    PanelBody,
    PanelRow
} from '@wordpress/components';
import { useState } from '@wordpress/element';
import './editor.scss';
import {options, catagories}from './container';
import { mapFile } from './app';
export default function Edit({ attributes, setAttributes }) {
    const blockProps = useBlockProps();
    const { backgroundColor, textColor } = attributes;

    const updateGroupId = (val) => {
        setAttributes({ GroupId: parseInt(val) });
    }
    const onChangeBackgroundColor = (BackgroundColor) => {
        setAttributes({ backgroundColor: BackgroundColor })
    }
    const onChangeTextColor = (TextColor) => {
        setAttributes({ textColor: TextColor })
    }   
    const stringArray = catagories.map(JSON.stringify);
    const uniqueStringArray = new Set(stringArray);
    const uniqueArray = Array.from(uniqueStringArray, JSON.parse);
    const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState('vtalk');
    const handleSelectChange = (event) => {
          setSelectedValue(event.target.value);
          console.log(event.target.value);
        }
    const mapFile = options.filter((m, idx) => idx < 5 && m.catagory == selectedValue).map((m) => { return (<div class="blog-stamp"><img src={m.image} width="200" height="200" /><h3 class="stamp-title">{m.label}</h3><p class="stamp-excerpt">{m.content}</p><p class="button-parent"><a href={m.link} class="sfs-button" style={{ backgroundColor: backgroundColor, color: textColor }}>Read more</a></p></div>) });
    return (
        <div {...blockProps}>
            <InspectorControls>
                <PanelColorSettings
                    title={__('Button Color settings', 'sfs-block')}
                    initialOpen={false}
                    colorSettings={[
                        {
                            value: textColor,
                            onChange: onChangeTextColor,
                            label: __('Button Text color', 'sfs-block')
                        },
                        {
                            value: backgroundColor,
                            onChange: onChangeBackgroundColor,
                            label: __('Button Background color', 'sfs-block')
                        }
                    ]}
                />
                <PanelBody
                    title={__('catagory filter', 'sfs-block')}
                    initialOpen={true}
                >
                    <PanelRow>
                        <fieldset>
                        <select value={selectedValue} onChange={handleSelectChange}>
                                {uniqueArray.map((cat) => {
                                    return <option value={cat.catagory}>{cat.catagory}</option>
                                })}
                            </select>
                        </fieldset>
                    </PanelRow>
                </PanelBody>
            </InspectorControls>
            {console.log(uniqueArray)}
            <p class="blog-stamp-parent">{mapFile}</p>
            </div>

    );
}
```

Save.js

```
import { useBlockProps } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
import { useState } from '@wordpress/element';
import {options} from './container';

export default function save({attributes}) {
    const [selectedValue] = useState('vtalk');
    const mapFile = options.filter((m, idx) => idx < 5 && m.catagory == selectedValue).map((m) => { return (<div class="blog-stamp"><img src={m.image} width="200" height="200" /><h3 class="stamp-title">{m.label}</h3><p class="stamp-excerpt">{m.content}</p><p class="button-parent"><a href={m.link} class="sfs-button" style={{ backgroundColor: backgroundColor, color: textColor }}>Read more</a></p></div>) });
    const { backgroundColor, textColor } = attributes;
    return (
        <div{ ...useBlockProps.save() }>
        <p class="blog-stamp-parent">{mapFile}</p>
        </div>
    );
}
```

The two issues seem to be that the selectedValue isn't being imported over from edit.js to save.js. The other issue is the useState not being imported over from Edit.js to Save.js.
I am not really sure how to approach the 2 issues and solve them. I hope it's an easy fix.
I am a newbie to React so any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message is:

```
@ > Error: Switching useSelect from mapping to mapping is not allowed
at Qe (data.min. js?ver=dc5f...34f3da29c8d5:9:2838)
at Ys (editor.min.js?ver=5a...5cf7808ee:12:140105)
at editor.min.js?ver=5a..5cf7808ee: 12: 142791
at wt (react-dom.min. js?ver=18.2.0:10:47637)
at vr (react-dom 56452)
at js (react-dom 121453)
at wl (react-dom
at bl (react-dom
at yl (react-dom.m.
at il (react—dom.min.is?ver=18.2.0:10:85274)
```

Based on the code you have provided, `useSelect` is not explicitly used. That could mean the error is either coming from a different part of your block code not shown or indirectly triggered by how components and hooks are utilized in the provided snippet.

Two other questions (without answer) illustrate that error message:

- "[When entering some blocks it gives react-dom.min.js on console "Switching useSelect from mapping to mapping"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77007757/6309)"
- "[Wordpress Gutenberg or React - useSelect for dynamic data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76573295/6309)"

It could be related to state management or data fetching within the WordPress block editor context that was not directly shown in your snippets.
[`useSelect`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-data/#useselect) is a hook provided by the [`@wordpress/data` package](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-data/) that allows you to select data from the WordPress data store.

If you are using `useSelect` elsewhere in your block or custom store, make sure you are not dynamically changing the mapping function passed to `useSelect`. The mapping function should be consistent, and not change based on state or props. See "[Using Button from Wordpress components does not work when used for frontend](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/421841)" as an illustration.

Avoid conditional logic inside the mapping function of `useSelect` that could lead to different hooks being called in different render cycles. React requires hooks to be called in the same order across renders. And make sure all hooks are called in the same order on every render. That includes `useSelect`, which should not be conditionally called nor should its arguments dynamically change in a way that alters its behavior significantly between renders.